# Differentiation under integral sign in two different ways

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I'm trying to convince myself that differentiating under the integral sign works with the following example:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^b \sin(xt) dx= \int_a^b \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \sin(xt)dx
\end{equation}

On one hand, we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^b \sin(xt)dx = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\left.\frac{-\cos(xt)}{t}\right\vert_a^b\right) = \frac{d}{dt} \left[\frac{\cos(at)}{t} - \frac{\cos(bt)}{t}\right] = \frac{1}{t}(\sin(bt)b - \sin(at)a) + \frac{1}{t^2}(\cos(bt) - \cos(at))
\end{equation}

On the other we have
\begin{equation}
\int_a^b \frac{d}{dt}\sin(xt)dx = \int_a^b t\cos(xt)dx = \left. \sin(xt) \right\vert_a^b = \sin(bt) - \sin(at)
\end{equation}

It's not clear to me how these 2 expressions can be simplified to be the same.

Comment: you missed dx in certain places

Comment: and your differentiation is wrong  $ \frac{d}{dt } \sin(xt) = x \cos(xt)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget that we are differentiating with respect to t rather than x.
$$
\begin{align}
 &\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^b \sin(xt)dx\\
=& \int_a^b \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \sin(xt)dx\\
=& \int_a^b x \cos(xt)dx
\end{align}
$$
and we can continue by doing integration by parts. We should now get the same answer either way.

Answer (score 2):

Your second equation should be
$$\int\limits_{a}^{b}x\cos(xt)dx=\frac{1}{t^2}(bt\sin(bt)+\cos(bt)-at\sin(at)-\cos(at))$$

For this example can be used [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Proofs), because integrand and its partial derivatives are continuous.